# How to change Column names in a SQL Table to Capital letters instead of small letters

Tags: sql

I have tables in my SQL database where some columns are named in small letters.
I would like to change the column names to all capital letters.

What is the best way to do it?

Comment: That was answered previously here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5270416/how-to-change-all-column-name-to-upper-case-for-all-the-tables-in-one-database-o

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to change all column name to UPPER CASE for all the tables in one database of MS SQL Server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5270416/how-to-change-all-column-name-to-upper-case-for-all-the-tables-in-one-database-o)

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using `postgresql`, `oracle`, `sql-server`, `db2`, ...